# Remove space between ul

Tags: html, css

I'm creating a list using `<ul>`, but I need it to be "united". Even though I removed all of the borders, padding and margins, it is still creating a space between the images. How can I remove it?

```
<h4>An Unordered List:</h4>
<ul>
  <li><img class="nomarge" ..../></li>
  <li><img class="nomarge" ..../></li>
  <li><img class="nomarge" ..../></li>
</ul>
<ul>
  <li><img class="nomarge" ..../></li>
  <li><img class="nomarge" ..../></li>
  <li><img class="nomarge" ..../></li>
</ul>
```

CSS

```
ul {
    padding: 0px 0px 0px 0px;
    margin: 0px 0px 0px 0px;
    border:  0px 0px 0px 0px;
    display: table;
    table-layout: fixed;
    display: inline;
}

li {
    padding: 0px 0px 0px 0px;
    border: 0px 0px 0px 0px;
    margin: 0px 0px 0px 0px;  
    display: table-cell;

}
```

Comment: using negative values could be a way...

Comment: If you have `0px` as a value, you safely can ommit the unit. `0px` is the same as `0em`, `0%` and so on.

Comment: Do the images need to be in one row or in multiple rows?

Answer (score 8, accepted):

Use this css:

```
img{ display: block;}
```

Comment: Thanks for formatting, Pete!

Answer (score 2):

What are the styles set on the `img` tag? You should set those to 0 as well. By the way, if you are setting pixel dimensions for all sides (top, bottom, left, right) of an element with css, you can do a shorthand of of just `0` (without units) instead of repeating `0px` four times.

That is:

```
border: 0;
padding: 0;
margin: 0;
```

Comment: img {
  max-width: 100%;
  border: 0;
  -ms-interpolation-mode: bicubic;
  width: auto;
  height: auto;
}

Comment: @PedroSilva Set the padding and margin to 0, too. User agent stylesheets normally throw a little padding on images by default. Is there a link I can look at?

Comment: yes, thanks, I did know, this "long code" was just to make sure I was doing it right. :)

Comment: @jefffabiny Which user agent puts padding on images? Never seen this.

Comment: @kleinfreund Perhaps I'm mistaken; I can't seem to find any atm. I use so many libraries most the time I'm actually quite surprised what I'm finding as default UA styling. I just wanted to be sure that wasn't the offending element.

Answer (score 2):

You need to use `display: table-cell;` for `UL` element. Here is what I have achieved.

http://jsfiddle.net/REmUC/

Answer (score 1):

Add `img { vertical-align: sub; }` and it should work.

```
ul {
    padding: 0px 0px 0px 0px;
    margin: 0px 0px 0px 0px;
    border:  0px 0px 0px 0px;
    display: table;
}

li {
    padding: 0px 0px 0px 0px;
    border: 0px 0px 0px 0px;
    margin: 0px 0px 0px 0px;  
    display: table-cell;
}

img {
    vertical-align: sub;
}
```

http://jsfiddle.net/pulleasy/Cw3Gj/

Answer (score 1):

The gap between your image comes from the `vertical-align: baseline;` all images (inline-block elements) have assigned by default. This way an image sits on the same line as normal text would. This could be useful, but isn't in your usecase.

Set this property to middle to avoid this problem:

```
img {
    vertical-align: middle;
}
```

Answer (score 1):

Try this CSS:

```
ul {
    padding: 0px;
    border:  0px;
    display: table;
    table-layout: fixed;
    display: inline;
}

li {
    padding: 0px;
    border: 0px;
    display: table-cell;
    border-spacing: 0px 0px;
    border-collapse: collapse;
}
img {
    padding: 0px;
    margin: 0px;
}
```